# why magento custom category layout showing product list twice

Tags: magento-1.8

here is the custom layout xml i am using:

```
 <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">

            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>


               </block>
```

i am seeing products twice in front end.

Comment: give more details. where did you put this code ? how did you set product collection etc

Comment: i have put this code to "Custom Layout Update" in category i did not understand your mean about  "product collection"

Comment: ok got it. only one thing to know more? why did you add this code ? or what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: actually theme layout not working and i could not figure out it. So i try to add the custom layout for it and its working fine just showing products twice

Comment: and how do the product shows now ? same product are appearing one after another or are they appearing seperateley ?

Comment: yes separate i think its rendering twice but i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

You have added this layout update via admin side. The layout update that you are used actually will create a new category view section under content section along with the default one.

There are two types of categories basically

- **Default Categories** :- Categories which do not possess layered navigation
- **Layered Categories** :- Categories which do possess layered navigation

Depending upon the type of category, Magento uses two desperate layout handles for them. For default categories, it uses `catalog_category_default` and for `catalog_category_layered`. These two layout handles will not process simultaneously.

Now Magento defines this layout handles in `catalog.xml` file. So take a look on these handles over there

File : `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/catalog.xml`

```
 <reference name="content">

        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
             .....
            </block>
            .....
        </block>
        ...
</reference>
```

(Above I showed only relevant sections)

Both of this layout handle already defines category-view block and product-list block over there.

Now, after processing the above layout update handle, then magento will take into consider your custom admin layout update that you have included via admin section. Your custom layout updation again do the same thing that is done by above mentioned layout handles here. That is why you are viewing two lists.

In order to avoid this, you need to refer blocks that are included through layout handles `catalog_category_default` or `catalog_category_layered` and then do customization then. That is you can refer a category-view block like this

```
<reference name="category.products">
     <!-- custom udpates comes here-->
</reference>
```

Similarly product-list block can be refered as

```
<reference name="product_list">
     <!-- custom udpates comes here-->
</reference>
```

So if you just need to set column via your custom update, then you can use this

```
<reference name="content>
    <reference name="product_list">
         <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
    </reference>
</reference>
```

This will set column count for existing product list block that is defined via category specific layout handles, instead of new one.

Comment: solution did not work but  it given me an idea i have comment the catalog.xml <reference name="content" 
an i did it :D

Comment: this code will not work if you need to set column. I just show you how your code will looks like, in order to avoid mutiple product list

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<remove name="product_list"/>
```

after the first line:

```
<reference name="content">
     <remove name="product_list"/>
     ...
```

in your custom xml design